# After deployment of contract getting error: "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-deployment

I have a simple contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Main {

function getValue() constant returns (bool){
  return true;
 }
}
```

I just need to create a web interface that can fetch this value for me.

I unboxed webpack in empty repo by `>truffle unbox webpack`, deleted the previous contracts, changed the *index.html* and *app.js* files, changed the *2_deploy_contracts.js* accordingly but the **error** i get on console of the browser is:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: VM Exception while processing
>   transaction: revert

Here is my *index.html* and *app.js* file.

```
 <html>

   <head>
     <title>Truffle 3 Frontend Demo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>


   <script src="./app.js"></script>
   <script src="../node_modules/web3/dist/web3.js" type="text/javascript">       </script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
</html>
```

and my app.js file is

```
import { default as Web3 } from 'web3'
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'
import Main_artifact from '../../build/contracts/Main.json'

const TESTRPC_HOST = 'localhost'
const TESTRPC_PORT = '8545'

function component () {
  var element = document.createElement('div')
  console.error("hi");
  let provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(`http://${TESTRPC_HOST}:${TESTRPC_PORT}`)
  let main = contract(Main_artifact)
  main.setProvider(provider)

  main.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      console.log(instance);

    var s = instance.getValue(); //instance.getValue.call() doesnt work either
    return s;
}).then(function(result){
    element.innerHTML = `value: ${result}`
    console.log(result)
});


  return element
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is the `constant` keyword on your function.

Per [this](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/992) issue on the solidity repository:

> the keyword `constant` is invalid on functions

Try removing that and redeploying the contract.

Comment: Sorry to revert back so late, I did remove it and still got an error, I upgraded my truffle to 4.0.4 from 4.0.1 and surprisingly it worked. I don't know if truffle did it or removing the keyword but it worked. Thanks for helping.